# Pattern matching using grep

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

Assuming we have one input string like

```
Nice
```

And we have the pattern

```
D*A*C*N*a*g*.h*ca*e
```

then "Nice" will match the pattern. (`*` means 0 or more occurrence, `.` means one char)
I think using grep is better than java in this case(maybe). How can I do it in grep?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same regular expression:

```
grep 'D*A*C*N*a*g*.h*ca*e' <<EOF
Nice
EOF
```

---

> If the input is "Nicely" it still prints it! How does it work?

The current regex looks for the pattern anywhere on the line.  If it must match exactly (the whole line), then add anchors to start (`^`) and end (`$`) of line:

```
grep '^D*A*C*N*a*g*.h*ca*e$' <<EOF
Nice
Nicely
Darce
Darcy
Darcey
EOF
```

Comment: if the input is "Nicely" it still print it! how does it work?